# How to check connection in c# webbrowser control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I code simple web browser and i want to show message when the connection is not available.I used "try catch" but it not work.How I detect my network connection is available or not.

Comment: but it not work means? please be more specific

Answer (score 0):

Ping a DNS that is almost up Like 4.2.2.4,4.2.2.3,4.2.2.2

```
Ping myPing = new Ping();
String host = "4.2.2.4;
byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
int timeout = 1000;
PingOptions pingOptions = new PingOptions();
PingReply reply = myPing.Send(host, timeout, buffer, pingOptions);
if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success {
  // presumably online
}
```

Comment: above code return true for both online and offline